# Writing bytes in client less than expected

Tags: c++, file, sockets, stream

I'm trying to use a UDP socket in C++ to send data between a client and server as a project in my university. The file I'm trying to send is an HTML document called `s.html`. It's **1,814,247** bytes in size.

When the file is sent, I see two different numbers at the client, the first one is the total number of bytes received minus the size of the header of each packet - which is 8 bytes.

It says that I received **1,814,239** bytes "the number written at the right terminal". So, there are 8 bytes that are missing in the receive from function.

[image: Output of the operation]

The bigger issue is when I try to inspect the file size in its directory, it gives me **1,810,500** bytes, which is far away from the real number.

[image: Real size written]

The structs of packets, data packet and acknowledge packet:

```
struct ack_packet {
    uint16_t chsum;
    uint16_t len;
    uint16_t ackno;
};
struct packet {
    uint16_t chsum;
    uint16_t len;
    uint16_t seqno;
    uint16_t finished;
    char data[500];
};
```

Here is the code of the server part of interest, if not enough for you to understand the problem, tell me and I'll just upload the whole code.

```
const size_t chunkSize = 500;
for (uint16_t seqno = 0; seqno < fileSize / chunkSize; ++seqno) {
    packet pkt;
    pkt.seqno = (seqno);
    pkt.len = (chunkSize+8);
    pkt.chsum = 88; // random now
    pkt.finished = 88; // not 1
    memcpy(pkt.data, fileContent.data() + seqno * chunkSize, chunkSize);
    if(seqno == fileSize / chunkSize - 1 && fileSize % chunkSize == 0)
        pkt.finished = 1;
     /**
     * The real business starts*/
     ssize_t b = sendto(newSock, &pkt, pkt.len, 0, &clntAddr, clntAddrLen);
     if(b < 0)
         perror("sendto() failed");
     ack_packet receivedPacket{};
     recvfrom(newSock, (void*)&receivedPacket, 6, MSG_WAITALL,&clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
     if((receivedPacket.ackno) != seqno){
         seqno--;
      }
}
size_t lastChunkSize = fileSize % chunkSize;
if (lastChunkSize > 0) {
    packet pkt;
    pkt.seqno = fileSize / chunkSize; // Finished
    pkt.len = (lastChunkSize);
    memcpy(pkt.data, fileContent.data() + fileSize / chunkSize * chunkSize, lastChunkSize);
    pkt.chsum = 0;
    pkt.finished = 1;
    ssize_t b = sendto(newSock, &pkt, pkt.len, 0, &clntAddr, clntAddrLen);
    if(b == lastChunkSize)
        cout << "Success size" << endl;
        ack_packet receivedPacket;
        recvfrom(newSock, (void*)&receivedPacket, 2, MSG_WAITALL, &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
        cout << "Acknowledged message " << receivedPacket.ackno << endl;
 }
```

Here is the code of interest in the client:

```
int s = 0;
struct sockaddr temp{};
socklen_t sz;
uint16_t waiting_for_package_x = 0;
while(true){
    packet receivedPacket{};
    numBytes = recvfrom(sock, (void*)&receivedPacket, 508, MSG_WAITALL,
                        &temp, &sz);
    s+=numBytes-8;
    if (numBytes < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("recvfrom() failed");
    if(receivedPacket.seqno != waiting_for_package_x){
        cout << receivedPacket.seqno << " " << waiting_for_package_x << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    waiting_for_package_x++;
    outputFile.write(receivedPacket.data, receivedPacket.len-8);
    ack_packet ackPacket{};
    ackPacket.chsum= (0);
    ackPacket.ackno= (receivedPacket.seqno);
    ackPacket.len = (6);
    sendto(sock, &ackPacket, 6,
               0, &temp, sz);
    if(receivedPacket.finished == 1)
        break;
}
```

`s` is the variable that tells me in the client how many bytes are received.

I suspected the write function in the `ofstream` to be ignoring some of the write operations, maybe because it has some sort of internal buffer that was filled during some of the receives. However, I think that this is not right.

Comment: is is the variable that tells me in the client how many bytes received

I mean 's', a variable in the client

Comment: C++ is not C, don't spam tags.

Comment: One observation:  `ackPacket.chsum= (0);` -- `ackPacket.len = (6);` -- Why are you unnecessarily wearing out your parentheses keys on your keyboard?  This could simply be: `ackPacket.chsum = 0;` -- `ackPacket.len = 6;`.  You do this in other places also.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean it, some of the libraries I use were in annotated as c libraries so Iwrote c. I'm sorry again

Comment: if `numBytes` is unsigned then `numBytes-8` will produce unexpected output, even if its not then if `numBytes-8` is less than `0` `s+=numBytes-8` is still incorrect before you've checked whether `numBytes` is more than 8

Comment: You don't add 8 to `len` in the final packet, but you subtract 8 when you've received it.

Comment: Also, the sequence number for the final "ack" is 3627, but you send 3629 packets (3628 whole ones and one last "chunk").

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes you're right, i wat sending them to some function first then passing the result, so I was lazy i didn't remove the parentheses

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for you response! I added a condition to make sure that this case doesn't happen and it doesn't happen

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you so much! this solves the issue of wrong number in the code.

Comment: @molbdnilo after fixing the problem prints 3628 normally
but stills write fewer bytes

Comment: The size discrepancy is suspiciously close to the number of packets. Have you tested with other files to see if you could spot a pattern? (Both "ends" are Linux, right?)

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, both are linux. and I thank you so much for your help, the issue was that I don't close the file, once I closed it it worked well

Comment: @AbdullahTaman just on a side note - why are you implementing your own protocol this by hand, instead of using an established UDP-based file transfer protocol such as [TFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, it's strange indeed. But this is required as an assignment in school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I don't close the file. Once it was closed data was written right.
Alhamdullilah this was the problem